# java image color formulas

Tags: java, colors

I know the java code for grayscale is this( 0.2126 * red  + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue(
I was wondering if anyone knows how I can find more variety of coloring formulas, like if i want to make the picture old fashion way, more orange, make it brighter, or darker ... sharper and so on

```
 int pixel = image.getRGB(j, i);
 int red = (pixel) & 0xff;
 int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
 int blue = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
 int newPixel = (int) (0.2126 * red  + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue);
                    image1.setRGB(j, i, newPixel);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old fashion way you mention is called "sepia" effect. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5132015/328725) particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5132043/328725) which points out to the following code snippet (note that I did not write this code, just helping out in finding answers to your question)

```
/**
*
* @param img Image to modify
* @param sepiaIntensity From 0-255, 30 produces nice results
* @throws Exception
*/
public static void applySepiaFilter(BufferedImage img, int
sepiaIntensity) throws Exception
{
// Play around with this. 20 works well and was recommended
// by another developer. 0 produces a grey image
int sepiaDepth = 20;

int w = img.getWidth();
int h = img.getHeight();

WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();

// We need 3 integers (for R,G,B color values) per pixel.
int[] pixels = new int[w*h*3];
raster.getPixels(0, 0, w, h, pixels);

// Process 3 ints at a time for each pixel. Each pixel has 3 RGB
colors in array
for (int i=0;i<pixels.length; i+=3)
{
int r = pixels[i];
int g = pixels[i+1];
int b = pixels[i+2];

int gry = (r + g + b) / 3;
r = g = b = gry;
r = r + (sepiaDepth * 2);
g = g + sepiaDepth;

if (r>255) r=255;
if (g>255) g=255;
if (b>255) b=255;

// Darken blue color to increase sepia effect
b-= sepiaIntensity;

// normalize if out of bounds
if (b<0) b=0;
if (b>255) b=255;

pixels[i] = r;
pixels[i+1]= g;
pixels[i+2] = b;
}
raster.setPixels(0, 0, w, h, pixels);
}
```

Comment: @behzad_b I am assuming the first two photos on the following wiki article is what you meant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_print_toning

Answer (score 1):

I would just play with the numbers.

> more orange,

more red and a little more green (red + green = yellow)

> brighter

increase all the factors

> darker

decrease all the factors

> sharper

This is specific filter which compare surrounding pixels to find edges. It not just a matter of playing with the colours.

BTW: You should add capping of the values. i.e. Math.min(255, Math.max(0, value))

Comment: Do I just play with numbers to make the image more blur?

Comment: blur is also a filter (the opposite of sharpen in some ways) You have to consider all the pixels around to get a blurred image (and not change the colours)

Comment: so what should I do, how do i apply those filters

Comment: blur and sharpen are usually implemented as matrix operations on the entire image, I am not sure if it would be a good idea to attempt to implement them in java, especially for larger images. You could check for libraries of course but I doubt any useful library would be free

Comment: for applying to a website, what else can i use?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the proportion between the color channels in order to change the scene "atmosphere". The images below were created using the [ColorChannel](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/plugins/colorChannel.html) plug-in.

[image]

The algorithm source code is presented below. The method *getAttribute()* gets the parameters (red,gree,blue) passed by the user. The methods *getIntComponent0*, *getIntComponent1* and *getIntComponent2* get each color channel (red, gree and blue). The method *setIntColor* sets back the value of each channel.

```
@Override
public void process
(
    MarvinImage imageIn,
    MarvinImage imageOut,
    MarvinAttributes attrOut,
    MarvinImageMask mask,
    boolean preview
) {

    int vr = (Integer)getAttribute("red");
    int vg = (Integer)getAttribute("green");
    int vb = (Integer)getAttribute("blue");

    double mr = 1+Math.abs((vr/100.0)*2.5);
    double mg = 1+Math.abs((vg/100.0)*2.5);
    double mb = 1+Math.abs((vb/100.0)*2.5);

    mr = (vr > 0? mr : 1.0/mr);
    mg = (vg > 0? mg : 1.0/mg);
    mb = (vb > 0? mb : 1.0/mb);

    int red,green,blue;
    for(int y=0; y<imageIn.getHeight(); y++){
        for(int x=0; x<imageIn.getWidth(); x++){
            red = imageIn.getIntComponent0(x, y);
            green = imageIn.getIntComponent1(x, y);
            blue = imageIn.getIntComponent2(x, y);

            red     = (int)Math.min(red * mr, 255);
            green   = (int)Math.min(green * mg, 255);
            blue    = (int)Math.min(blue * mb, 255);

            imageOut.setIntColor(x, y, 255, red, green, blue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will you explain how to achieve this with OpenCV(java)?