# Java Convert a greyscale and sepia version of an image with BufferedImage

Tags: java, image-processing

I want to read an image and convert and output the original image, a greyscale version, and a sepia version. I am having trouble with the conversion, not very familiar with BufferedImage, and especially having problems with getRGB and setRGB method. I have this so far

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;

public class ChangeColor{
  static BufferedImage readImage( String Pic ) throws Exception {

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( new File("Pic.jpg") );
    return( image );
  }

  public static void saveImage( BufferedImage img, File file ) throws IOException {

        ImageWriter      writer = null;
        java.util.Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

        if( iter.hasNext() ){
            writer = (ImageWriter)iter.next();
        }

        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream( file );
        writer.setOutput(ios);

        ImageWriteParam param = new JPEGImageWriteParam( java.util.Locale.getDefault() );
        param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT) ;
        param.setCompressionQuality(0.98f);

        writer.write(null, new IIOImage( img, null, null ), param);

    }

  public static BufferedImage color2gray( BufferedImage inImage ) {

    int            width    = inImage.getWidth();
    int            height   = inImage.getHeight();
    BufferedImage  outImage = new BufferedImage( width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR );

    for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
           Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
           int red = (int)(c.getRed() * 0.2126);
           int green = (int)(c.getGreen() * 0.7152);
           int blue = (int)(c.getBlue() *0.0722);
           Color newColor = new Color(red+green+blue,
           red+green+blue,red+green+blue);
           image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
           }
    }

    return( outImage );
  }

  public static BufferedImage color2sepia( BufferedImage inImage ) {

    int            width    = inImage.getWidth();
    int            height   = inImage.getHeight();
    BufferedImage  outImage = new BufferedImage( width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR );
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
           Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
           int red = (int)(c.getRed());
           int green = (int)(c.getGreen());
           int blue = (int)(c.getBlue());
           Color newColor = new Color(red* .393)+(green*.769)+(blue* .189),
           (red* .349)+(green*.686)+(blue* .168),(red* .272)+(green*.534)+(blue* .131);
           image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
           }
    }
    return( outImage );
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedImage colorImage, grayImage, sepiaImage;

    if (args.length != 1)
        System.out.println( "" );
    else
    {
        colorImage = readImage  ( args[0] );
    grayImage  = color2gray ( colorImage );
    sepiaImage = color2sepia( colorImage );

    saveImage( grayImage,  new File( "greyPic.jpg" + args[0] ) );
    saveImage( sepiaImage, new File( "sepiaPic.jpg"+ args[0] ) );
    }
  }

}
```

This is an image of what the output should look like:

[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Gray scaling is rather easy, sepia not so much.  I stole the algorithm off the net...

[image: Convert]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ColorAlteration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                try {
                    BufferedImage master = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\hold\\thumbnails\\_cg_836___Tilting_Windmills___by_Serena_Clearwater.png"));
                    BufferedImage gray = toGrayScale(master);
                    BufferedImage sepia = toSepia(master, 80);

                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                    panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(master)));
                    panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(gray)));
                    panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(sepia)));

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static BufferedImage toGrayScale(BufferedImage master) {
        BufferedImage gray = new BufferedImage(master.getWidth(), master.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // Automatic converstion....
        ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
        op.filter(master, gray);

        return gray;
    }

    public static BufferedImage toSepia(BufferedImage img, int sepiaIntensity) {

        BufferedImage sepia = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        // Play around with this.  20 works well and was recommended
        //   by another developer. 0 produces black/white image
        int sepiaDepth = 20;

        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();

        WritableRaster raster = sepia.getRaster();

        // We need 3 integers (for R,G,B color values) per pixel.
        int[] pixels = new int[w * h * 3];
        img.getRaster().getPixels(0, 0, w, h, pixels);

        //  Process 3 ints at a time for each pixel.  Each pixel has 3 RGB
        //    colors in array
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 3) {
            int r = pixels[i];
            int g = pixels[i + 1];
            int b = pixels[i + 2];

            int gry = (r + g + b) / 3;
            r = g = b = gry;
            r = r + (sepiaDepth * 2);
            g = g + sepiaDepth;

            if (r > 255) {
                r = 255;
            }
            if (g > 255) {
                g = 255;
            }
            if (b > 255) {
                b = 255;
            }

            // Darken blue color to increase sepia effect
            b -= sepiaIntensity;

            // normalize if out of bounds
            if (b < 0) {
                b = 0;
            }
            if (b > 255) {
                b = 255;
            }

            pixels[i] = r;
            pixels[i + 1] = g;
            pixels[i + 2] = b;
        }
        raster.setPixels(0, 0, w, h, pixels);

        return sepia;
    }
}
```

You can find the original posting for the sepia algorithm [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.java.programmer/nSCnLECxGdA)

And because I'm stubborn...I changed the sepia algorithm to work with alpha based images...

```
public static BufferedImage toSepia(BufferedImage img, int sepiaIntensity) {

    BufferedImage sepia = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    // Play around with this.  20 works well and was recommended
    //   by another developer. 0 produces black/white image
    int sepiaDepth = 20;

    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();

    WritableRaster raster = sepia.getRaster();

    // We need 3 integers (for R,G,B color values) per pixel.
    int[] pixels = new int[w * h * 3];
    img.getRaster().getPixels(0, 0, w, h, pixels);

    for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {

            int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y);
            Color color = new Color(rgb, true);
            int r = color.getRed();
            int g = color.getGreen();
            int b = color.getBlue();
            int gry = (r + g + b) / 3;

            r = g = b = gry;
            r = r + (sepiaDepth * 2);
            g = g + sepiaDepth;

            if (r > 255) {
                r = 255;
            }
            if (g > 255) {
                g = 255;
            }
            if (b > 255) {
                b = 255;
            }

            // Darken blue color to increase sepia effect
            b -= sepiaIntensity;

            // normalize if out of bounds
            if (b < 0) {
                b = 0;
            }
            if (b > 255) {
                b = 255;
            }

            color = new Color(r, g, b, color.getAlpha());
            sepia.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());

        }
    }

    return sepia;
}
```

Comment: Love your choice of images :)

Comment: @peeskillet Yea for MegaTokyo...thought the sepia came out a little yellow, need to play with the intensity value more...

Comment: That is interesting, I will take more a look into it. Do you know of anything I could do to fix my original code? I would like to try to get it to work rather than switching the algorithm entirely.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: The fastest (at least easiest) way to creating a sepia tone effect, is to first convert to grey, then use `RescaleOp` to scale/offset the reds, blues and greens (in effect very similar to what you have implemented above). +1 for the effort and good example though! :-)

Comment: @haraldK I was starting to get the impression that sepia was a type of gray scale.  Thanks for hint, I'll take more of a look at it!

Comment: Directly manipulating the image pixels (using setRGB method) is much slower.

Comment: @Rendicahya Well, the question is, are you after the result or the speed?  If you just have a bunch of images you want to apply a sepia filter so they can be used/processed for something else, then this works, if you want to do it because you want to present it, say, in a game, then no, it's not the fastest, as suggested by haraldk

Comment: @Rendicahya Besides, the question was about "how" to do it, how to make it more efficient :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer The code didn't work for me :( check my answer below:

Comment: @Salivan What I'm curious about is the fact that the two solutions are just about the same thing. I extract the pixel data directly (admitted isn't the fastest, but I was after the solution not the optimization), and I use Color to perform the bit wise operation, cause I'm to lazy to remember the bit positions, of, and mine should work on alpha based images, so, in what way didn't it work?

Comment: int[] pixels = new int[w * h * 3]; This line looks suspicious. Pixel value is an int, and then why did you multiply the size by 3 ? 
My code: **public static void main(String[] args){
        toSepia(new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB), 20);
}**
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30000*. After removing it, another error happened. And then I figured it out just now. It must be exactly equal to image channels, which it is A+R+G+B = 4. So, for transparent images it must be 4. And hey, I really really like the way you provide solutions. :)

Comment: @Salivan Not really I'm actually using that, must be left over from the original code :P (at least form the second example) This is why I'm probably using getRGB over getPixels :P

Answer (score 2):

I used @@MadProgrammer code to write this code. Which I think it is much more efficient.

1. Using raster data of the image instead of accessing each byte of image. Although it seems it copys the data into pixels array, it is not used in the program.
2. You are calling getRGB each time + getWidth() + getHeight() + getRed(), getGreen() + getBlue().
3. Writing colors directly into your image, I think it is a bottleneck once you write a color using setRGB, you will lose graphic processor benefits. (I read it somewhere, but can't find the link now.)
4. Converting the color back to Color object and getting it back using getRGB().

All I did was using bit-wise operators which it is very fast and then copied the pixel arrays once I was done working with it. Function call is expensive and I avoided them.

However, thanks for the idea, @MadProgrammer.

```
public static BufferedImage toSepia(BufferedImage image, int sepiaIntensity) {

    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    int sepiaDepth = 20;

    int[] imagePixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);

    for (int i = 0; i < imagePixels.length; i++) {
        int color = imagePixels[i];

        int r = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
        int g = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
        int b = (color) & 0xff;
        int gry = (r + g + b) / 3;

        r = g = b = gry;
        r = r + (sepiaDepth * 2);
        g = g + sepiaDepth;

        if (r > 255) {
            r = 255;
        }
        if (g > 255) {
            g = 255;
        }
        if (b > 255) {
            b = 255;
        }

        // Darken blue color to increase sepia effect
        b -= sepiaIntensity;

        // normalize if out of bounds
        if (b < 0) {
            b = 0;
        }
        if (b > 255) {
            b = 255;
        }

        imagePixels[i] = (color & 0xff000000) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
    }

    BufferedImage res = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    res.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, imagePixels, 0, width);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter interface for code reuse.

### FilterApp

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class FilterApp {
    public static ClassLoader loader = FilterApp.class.getClassLoader();
    public static String outputDir = "build";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedImage srcImage = loadImage("lobster.jpg");
            File dir = new File(outputDir);

            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            for (FilterType filter : FilterType.values()) {
                BufferedImage filteredImage = filter.applyFilter(srcImage);
                String filename = String.format("%s/lobster_%s", outputDir, filter.name().toLowerCase());
                writeImage(filteredImage, filename, "jpg");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static BufferedImage loadImage(String filename) throws IOException {
        return ImageIO.read(loader.getResourceAsStream("resources/" + filename));
    }

    private static void writeImage(BufferedImage image, String filename, String ext) throws IOException {
        ImageIO.write(image, ext, new File(filename + '.' + ext));
    }
}
```

### FilterType

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import filter.GreyscaleFilter;
import filter.ImageFilter;
import filter.InvertFilter;
import filter.SepiaFilter;

public enum FilterType {
    GREYSCALE(new GreyscaleFilter()),
    INVERT(new InvertFilter()),
    SEPIA_10(new SepiaFilter(10));

    private ImageFilter filter;

    public ImageFilter getFilter() { return filter; }

    public BufferedImage applyFilter(BufferedImage img) {
        return this.filter.apply(img);
    }

    private FilterType(ImageFilter filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }
}
```

### ImageFilter

```
package filter;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

/** Common Interface for different filters. */ 
public interface ImageFilter {
    public BufferedImage apply(BufferedImage img);
}
```

### GreyscaleFilter

```
package filter;

import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp;

public class GreyscaleFilter implements ImageFilter {
    @Override
    public BufferedImage apply(BufferedImage img) {
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getType());
        ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);

        op.filter(img, result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

### InvertFilter

```
package filter;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class InvertFilter implements ImageFilter {
    @Override
    public BufferedImage apply(BufferedImage img) {
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getType());

        for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
                int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y);
                Color color = new Color(rgb, true);
                int r = 255 - color.getRed();
                int g = 255 - color.getGreen();
                int b = 255 - color.getBlue();

                color = new Color(r, g, b, color.getAlpha());
                result.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

### SepiaFilter

```
package filter;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

// Algorithm obtained from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899824
public class SepiaFilter implements ImageFilter {
    private int intensity;

    public void setIntensity(int intensity) { this.intensity = intensity; }
    public int getIntensity() { return intensity; }

    public SepiaFilter(int intensity) {
        this.intensity = intensity;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedImage apply(BufferedImage img) {
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getType());
        // Play around with this.
        // 20 works well and was recommended by another developer.
        // 0 produces black/white image
        int sepiaDepth = 20;

        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();

        // We need 3 integers (for R,G,B color values) per pixel.
        int[] pixels = new int[w * h * 3];
        img.getRaster().getPixels(0, 0, w, h, pixels);

        for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
                int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y);
                Color color = new Color(rgb, true);
                int r = color.getRed();
                int g = color.getGreen();
                int b = color.getBlue();
                int gry = (r + g + b) / 3;

                r = g = b = gry;
                r = r + (sepiaDepth * 2);
                g = g + sepiaDepth;

                if (r > 255) { r = 255; }
                if (g > 255) { g = 255; }
                if (b > 255) { b = 255; }

                // Darken blue color to increase sepia effect
                b -= this.intensity;

                // normalize if out of bounds
                if (b < 0)   { b = 0; }
                if (b > 255) { b = 255; }

                color = new Color(r, g, b, color.getAlpha());
                result.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

### Output

Source Image

[image]

Generated Images

[image]
[image]
[image]